# Pythonnet stackoverflow exception in Python.Runtime.dll when calling Py.Import

Tags: c#, python, python.net

I'm using python 3.5 installed in a virtual conda environment. The stackoverflow happens during a call to Py.Import:

```
dynamic np = Py.Import("numpy");
```

This was once working on my machine, but I decided to reinstall my Python environment. I set PythonEngine.PythonPath to the location of my virtual environment. My root Python install is also version 3.5. If I uninstall numpy,  Py.Import fails expectedly due to the module not being found. If I reinstall numpy, I get a stackoverflow:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'
>   occurred in Python.Runtime.dll
>
> Worker Thread Python.Runtime.dll!Python.Runtime.ImportHook.**import** Normal
>                         [External Code]
>                         The maximum number of stack frames supported by Visual Studio has been exceeded.

Importing built-in python modules works. I tried importing one of my own modules with a print statement at the first line, and the print statement gets called twice, so something is fishy. Any ideas why the stackoverflow exception is occurring?

Python 3.5.3
64-bit
numpy 1.13.1
VS2015
Pythonnet 2.30-py35-dotnet

Comment: please provide the full traceback and exception

Comment: @denfromufa added stacktrace and full exception message

Comment: which versions of Python, numpy, pythonnet and .NET are you using? Also bitness (x86 or x64)?

Comment: What happens when you call pythonnet from root Python environment? How are you setting up the conda virtual environment?

Comment: If you installed pythonnet with nuget, then manually pick the 64bit version Python.Runtime.DLL reference from package subdirectory

Comment: You need to set PythonHome, not PythonPath. The latter is used for modules and packages.

Comment: @denfromufa thanks for the suggestions. i did manually switch to 64bit DLL. also, i just tried setting PythonHome (which was empty before) to my virtual env location, but still getting the stackoverflow. will try installing numpy into root environment and try running from root.

Comment: @denfromufa root environment worked!

Comment: did you activate your conda virtual environment before using it?! You can  do it from your .NET environment. Alternatively prepend `%PATH%` to include conda env. https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/463

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150878/discussion-between-kliao-and-denfromufa).